# What would be the most useful were-animals?

Tags: magic, creature-design, fauna, shapeshifters

I'm trying to develop a set of "were-animals". The rules of this universe are pretty classic, were-somethings turn into their animal counter-parts on full moons, and once transformed, they look like dark, twisted, amphetamine-abusing versions of said animals.

They also have related powers and personality traits in their human forms. The inspiration for these can come from the real animal or legends and folklore. For example were-wolves have a supernatural sense of smell and a tendency to form packs, were-foxes have a genius mind and a cruel sense of humor, were-sloths can take up to 10 naps a day, etc. The animal can be anything from ant to whale.

For now, my list includes : wolf, fox, owl, sloth, gecko, lynx, pangolin, tarsier, penguin, snake (a venomous one, I haven't decided yet) and naked mole rat.

---

Do you have a suggestion to expand this list?

The proposed were-beings should have useful abilities either in the context of a war or for everyday tasks.

Both transformed and human forms count. Transforming into a [were-tarsier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rBndmo8DKA&feature=youtu.be&t=1) sounds pretty lame, but being able to see behind your head can be useful in many situations.

---

Additional info:

The story is set on an alternative Earth, either in the 70's or 80's. A class of were-things can have a rich history, been the most important of all were-beings in the middle-ages and be completely useless today. What matters is that their powers have been either extremely dangerous or useful at some point of History.

Comment: What time are we in (modern-day, medieval, or ...?), as a pumped-up, intelligent animal will have different uses in different scenarios.

Comment: @Mikey The story is set on an alternative Earth, either in the 70's or 80's, but it's not very important. A class of were-things can have a rich history, been the most important/powerful of all were-beings in the middle-ages and be completely useless today. (A fall like this could even be interesting, actually)

Comment: Hi SpaceLizard. This is an interesting question, but it seems to me to be what we call "idea generation", since it is asking for a pretty much unbounded set of answers with no criteria to judge answers as good or bad. I suggest you take a look at [What's wrong with “idea generation” questions?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/522/29) on [meta], and adjust your question accordingly. For a start, try to include some objective criteria by which we can judge answers. I am putting the question on hold for the moment; if you fix it up a little, it should be eligible for reopening.

Comment: If you feel you need help in fixing up your question, you may want to try our [Sandbox for Proposed Questions](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/635/29), also  on [meta], or in our general chat room in [chat]. Note that if you [edit] your question during the "on hold" grace period, it will automatically enter the reopen review queue for community review. Also, please include all pertient information in the question itself; comments are subject to deletion.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If I add something like "The proposed were-beings should either have useful abilities or be unusual and funny.", does it count as an objective criteria or should I be more specific?

Comment: I think the "or be unusual and funny" would make your question "primarily opinion-based" in that case, because what is funny is inherently a question of opinions. However, if you state that answers must be about abilities that are *useful in the creature's daily life at least in either form* and to explain *how* the proposed ability meets that criteria, that could probably work. The key is to **phrase the question in such a way that we can *objectively* judge how well a given answer answers the question as asked.** (And don't be afraid to split it into multiple questions if that works better.)

Comment: [Vegeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegeta#Abilities)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Ok, the question is more specific than before, are there other changes I have to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can work as woodcutters and become were-beavers and gnaw trees at enormous rate like the Woodie character from "Don't Starve"!

[image: Woode the Woodcutter]
[image: Woodie the Werebeaver]

Comment: And now I want to know if there is any legend about beavers out there... I'll ask Google if he has any "Beaver Legend" for me.

Comment: @SpaceLizard DON'T google Beaver Legend!!!!

Comment: Actually with safe search on it's fine :)

Comment: I had an idea today - wereowls, and in human form they sleep on day, and active on night, also they have nigh-vision and very keen senses - they can work as scouts.